# rubbish instead of string display

Tags: c

The task is to be sure that phrases are can be readed vise versa or not (without spaces `' '`).

So I got the point and made some code. But when I made

```
printf("%s", str_1)
```

I found a lot of same russian letters.

For example my inputs are: '123' '321', but displayed rubbish

My `str_1[i]` is going to be like `123321` and then checked first and last and so on members.

After that I added in if condition `if(str[i] != 'М')` and now everything nice.

Please tell me what I did wrong and what is going on with `"M"`.

I hope my question is clear.

```
 #include "stdio.h"
    #include "locale.h"
    int main(){


    char str[100];
    char str_1[100];
    int i, j, k, l;
    j = 0;
    l = 0;

    fgets(str, 100, stdin); //we got array

    //how many chars before '\0'
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != 'М')
            {
                str_1[j] = str[i]; //made new array without spaces between words or whatever
                j++;
            }

        }

        j--; 

        for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                if(str_1[k] == str_1[j - 1 - k])
                    {
                        l++;
                    }
            }
        if( l == k)
            {
                printf(";) YES! good job!\n");
            }
        else
            {
                printf(";) NOT! I'm sorry!\n");
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, you skip over the end of the string, as you never check where it ends.

At least, this is my suspicion; I am not sure if it is the right reason.

You should check for `str[i] == '\0'` as well and then break the whole loop.

As I see, you even made this consideration in

> ```
> //how many chars before '\0'
> ```

but didn't include it in code.

A

```
for(i = 0; i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

should do the trick if you omit the `j--` afterwards.

Comment: thank you, Yes I missed this one, so now it works as it should be) and I got j-- after

Comment: @wm.p1us No, you should omit it, as you don't copy the `\0` byte.